# 1-Parameter subgroups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be an affine reductive group defined over a field of characteristic zero $k$, denote by $\bar{k}$ the algebraic closure of $k$, and by $k^{\times}$ the multiplicative group of $k$. Let $Z(G)$ be the center of $G$. Let $\lambda$ be a 1-parameter subgroup of $G$ defined over $k$. Suppose that $\lambda(k^{\times})\subset Z(G)$, 
is it true that $\lambda(\bar{k}^{\times})\subset Z(G)$ or can you give me a counterexample?

Comment: The field $k$ is infinite (since $\operatorname*{char}k=0$), so $k^{\times}$ is infinite. On the other hand, the property of a $x\in k^{\times}$ to satisfy $\lambda\left(x\right)\in Z\left(G\right)$ is an AND-combination of finitely many polynomial identities (I hope it's really "finitely many"), and we should be able to apply the standard Zariski argument (if a polynomial identity holds for an infinite subset of $k$, then it should also hold for all $k$).

Comment: Anyway, nothing changes if it's infinitely many polynomial identities...

Comment: The above is written from the above affine-groups-are-made-of-points viewpoint. From the scheme-theoretic viewpoint, you will probably have to do something like this: the preimage $\lambda^{-1}\left(Z\left(G\right)\right)$ is Zariski-closed (being the preimage of a Zariski-closed set) but contains the Zariski dense subset $k^{\otimes}$ of $\overline{k}^{\otimes}$, thus must be the whole $\overline{k}^{\otimes}$. I hope the Zariski topology makes sense here.

Comment: Read $\times$ for $\otimes$ please. Deformation professionelle of a Hopf algebraist...

Comment: $\lambda (k^\times)$ is a horrible notation as your $\lambda$ is neither split, nor even multiplicative...

Comment: Having said that, if your $\lambda$ is what you think it is (split+multiplicative), the statement is obviously true as $k^\times$ is Zariski dense in $\overline{k}^\times$. Please, clarify.

Comment: I think the OP means that $\lambda$ is a "$k$-cocharacter" of $G$ -- homomorphism $\mathbf{G}_m \to G$ defined over $k$. Then indeed the statement follows from the Zariski density of the $k$-points of the multiplicative group.